# How to get the size of a binary data posted to a php?

Tags: php, http-post, binary-data, filesize

My 3rd party app creates an image and store it in a variable and then post it to a php on the server. for security matters, I need to limit the upload size. Now that the binary data is not written to a file yet, how would I go around getting its size?

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$_data = $_POST['data']; //get the binary data from the client side.

    if($_data !=""){
       $handle = fopen($_path."/".$_ref.".png", "w");
       fwrite($handle,$_data);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$length = strlen($_POST['data']);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$_FILES['filename']['size']` to get the uploaded filesize

Comment: This won't work since the data is binary and not a file upload.